# Render dynamically Markdown Content in interactive React Code with Hooks (Different number/order of hooks problem!)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, markdown, react-navigation

Bonjour!

I want to create an mobile App which renders content written in markdown, similar to Obsidian. So far I successfully used the library `react-native-markdown-display` to render markdown pages with non-interactive content, e.g. text, images and son on. Now I want to add interactive markdown content with custom rules, e.g. a map view, which needs hooks to work properly. Because the pages can change by user input and each page has different (interactive) content, I run in the problem of *“Rendered more hooks than during the previous render”*.

What would be the best strategy to tackle this problem?

While playing around I found out that if I create two react components `Markdown` and `Markdown1`, which basically are the same components just with a different name. I can give each component different markdown content and conditionally render one or the other, without error. Would this be a good way to solve this problem? If yes how does react differentiate react components? How could I dynamically create `Markdown` components for different interactive content, which react could differentiate?

Would creating a screen in `react-navigation` dynamically  for every markdown page be a good solution?

---

**Edit:**
In React-Navigation screens can not be added dynamically during runtime, nevertheless it wouldn`t change the original problem.

I elaborated on the `Markdown` and `Markdown1` approach and found out that you can also assign keys, which appears to work in a similar way. I opened a new question regarding this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77497668/dynamic-number-of-hooks-legit-when-assigning-unique-key)

Comment: I think I know what your problem is, but to be sure I'd like to see the piece of code where the error is thrown. What is the hook in question? Is it useState?

Comment: I think you may have pasted the wrong library - "react-native-render-display" is for rendering to external screens

Comment: @ lorweth33: The kind of hook does not matter, for the error

@AshleyCoolman: Yes, thank you I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

I also dragged into same problem, but I resolved by split components

**When the error happen code like this:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View, 
useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';
import InsureIcon from './InsureIcon';
import { icons } from '../constants';
import InputText from './common/InputText';
import { ButtonLoad } from './common/ButtonLoad';

const InsureDetails = ({handleChange,proposerDetail}) => {
const [addMoreMembers,setAddMoreMembers]=useState(false)
const handleAddMember=()=>{
setAddMoreMembers(true)
  }
return (
  <ScrollView>
    <Text style={{fontSize:35,fontFamily:'serif',fontWeight:'bold', 
  marginVertical:30,color:'#696ac3'}}>
      Select members to insure
    </Text>
    <View style={styles.insurers}>
      <InsureIcon icon={icons.person} type="self" />
      <InsureIcon icon={icons.female} type="spouse" />
      <InsureIcon icon={icons.son} type="son" />
      <InsureIcon icon={icons.daughter} type="daughter" />
      <InsureIcon icon={icons.father} type="father" />
      <InsureIcon icon={icons.mother} type="mother" />
      {addMoreMembers &&
      <>
      <InsureIcon icon={icons.father} type="grand-father" />
      <InsureIcon icon={icons.mother} type="grand-mother" />
      </>
      }

      {!addMoreMembers &&
      <View style={{width:useWindowDimensions().width*.8,marginHorizontal:useWindowDimensions().width*.1}}>
        <ButtonLoad onPress={()=>handleAddMember()} title='Add more members'/>
      </View>}

    </View>
    <InputText
      label="Age of Eldest Member"
      icon={icons.calender}
      id='age'
      type={'numeric'}
      onChangeText={({ value }) => handleChange(value, id='age')}
      value={proposerDetail.age}

      />
  </ScrollView>
 );
 };

export default InsureDetails
```

**Error not coming after spliting components like this**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View, 
useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';
import InsureIcon from './InsureIcon';
import { icons } from '../constants';
import InputText from './common/InputText';
import { ButtonLoad } from './common/ButtonLoad';

const MoreMember=()=>{
return (
<>
<InsureIcon icon={icons.father} type="grand-father" />
<InsureIcon icon={icons.father} type="grand-father" />
</>
)
}

const AddMember=({handleAddMember})=>{
return <View style= 
{{width:useWindowDimensions().width*.8, 
marginHorizontal:useWindowDimensions().width*.1}}>
<ButtonLoad onPress={handleAddMember} title='Add more members'/>
</View>
}

const InsureDetails = ({handleChange,proposerDetail}) => {
const [addMoreMembers,setAddMoreMembers]=useState(false)
const handleAddMember=()=>{
setAddMoreMembers(true)
}
return (
  <ScrollView>
    <Text style={{ fontSize:35,fontFamily:'serif',fontWeight:'bold', 
marginVertical:30,color:'#696ac3'}}>
      Select members to insure
    </Text>
    <View style={styles.insurers}>
      <InsureIcon icon={icons.person} type="self" />
      <InsureIcon icon={icons.female} type="spouse" />
      <InsureIcon icon={icons.son} type="son" />
      <InsureIcon icon={icons.daughter} type="daughter" />
      <InsureIcon icon={icons.father} type="father" />
      <InsureIcon icon={icons.mother} type="mother" />
     {addMoreMembers&& <MoreMember/>}

      {!addMoreMembers && <AddMember handleAddMember={handleAddMember}/>
      }

    </View>
    <InputText
      label="Age of Eldest Member"
      icon={icons.calender}
      id='age'
      type={'numeric'}
      onChangeText={({ value }) => handleChange(value, id='age')}
      value={proposerDetail.age}

      />
  </ScrollView>
  );
 };

 export default InsureDetails
```

Comment: This is not the way to go as it isn't truly dynamic. You can add two more members or not, but you can't add any other number of members.

Comment: Also I don't see where would "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render" error appear, neithe in the first nor in the second example - are you sure you got it there?

Answer (score 0):

## Conditional/dynamic rendering

You can not call hooks conditionally. Calling hooks in loops, although I think it could be *legal*, is also at least shady and should be avoided. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render. Call them at the top level of a component (i.e. don't nest it inside of anything more than the component ifself).

[More on topic of "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render" error](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-rendered-more-hooks-than-during-previous-render)

I did ask if it's the `useState` hook which causes the error because I suppose you did something like below:

```
if (showAnotherMarkdown) {
  const [markdown, setMarkdown] = React.useState();
}
```

### Changing state of components

> How could I dynamically create Markdown components for different interactive content

I don't know anything about `react-native-markdown-display`, but I checked out their documentation and it seems that if you want to change what content the Markdown component displays you just provide a different data to it. Let's say you've got two constants holding markdown and two buttons which let you change which one is used:

```
const markdown1 = `# h1 This is a markdown`;
const markdown2 = `# h1 This is another markdown`;

const [markdown, setMarkdown] = React.useState(markdown1);

return (
  <div>
    My Markdown:

    <Markdown>
      {markdown}
    </Markdown>

    <Button onClick={() => setMarkdown(markdown1)}>
      show first markdown 
    </Button>

    <Button onClick={() => setMarkdown(markdown2)}>
      show the other markdown
    </Button>
  </div>
);
```

Instead of constants these could be files, data fetched from a server, user input - sky is the limit. What matters is what `setMarkdown` is called with, which in turn determines what sits in the state and then is passed to the `Markdown` component.

### Rendering lists

If you need to display a different set of elements based on some arbitrary data there is a number of ways you can achieve it.

You hold data in the state, like this:

```
const [markdownList, setMarkdownList] = React.useState([]);
```

then you map the data to elements, e.g. like this:

```
return (
  <div>
    Markdown list:
    
    {markdownList.map((markdown, index) => (
      <Markdown key={index}>
        {markdown}
      </Markdown>
    ))}
    
  </div>
);
```

I don't know where your markdown comes from so I will just provide a general way of adding some to the list:

```
function addMarkdown(newMarkdown) {
  setMarkdownList(prevList => [...prevList, newMarkdown]); //appending to the end 
}
```

If you hold an object or an array in the state, se sure to create a new one each time you want to update it since React compares references to tell if a change was made and does not examine contents of them.

A classic example is a Todo List. I encourage you to check out some examples. [Here is a full example of Todo list on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-todo-list-p912n?file=/src/TodoList.js).

## Component tree

> how does react differentiate react components?

It creates a virtual DOM tree. Elements of this tree correspond to elements displayed on the screen.

Also, JSX is transpiled to `React.createElement` calls:

```
const element = (
  <h1 className="greeting">
    Witaj, świecie!
  </h1>
);

const element = React.createElement(
  'h1',
  {className: 'greeting'},
  'Witaj, świecie!'
);
```

You can see that `'h1'` was passed to `createElement` so this is another piece by which React differenciates components - by the function (or tag) which is used to create the DOM tree.

In the example above I used a map to create an arbitrary set of elements. There is a caveat to that.

> JSX elements directly inside a map() call always need keys!

([React docs on rendering lists](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists))

The `key` is also used to differenciate elements. React holds data for each element and the `key` is necessary to assign state to the element which owns it. I used `index` as `key` which is fine as long as you don't perform any manipulation on the list other than adding to the end. If, for example, you would remove an element from the beginning of the list and the indices would shift, the states would not shift with them and second element would get state from the first, third from second and so on. The `key` needs to be unique. IDs and hashes are good as `key`s because they are usually unique.

## Disclaimer

You didn't provide and code so I had to guess some things and I'm not certain if anyhing from what I wrote above is going to be any helpful. Feel free to ask furher questions.