# Dynamic number of hooks legit when assigning unique key?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to render dynamic user generated markdown content in react code. The markdown content changes and the generated react code shall be reactive and needs hooks to do that. My first solution created the known error *"different number of hooks between renders"*, but if I give the markdown component a unique key per user content everything works fine without problems. In this example a video-player or a map-view is rendered, each with its own hooks.

**Question is my solution legit?**

```
function Markdown(userContent) {
  // parse userContent
  return <Some react code based on userContent including hooks />;
}

function App() {
  const [content, setContent] = useState("some markdown text ::render-video-player::");
  const someUniqueKey = useGiveMeUniqueKey();

  const otherUserContent = "some other markdown text ::render-map-view::";

  return (
    <>
      <Markdown key={someUniqueKey} userContent={content} />

      <Pressable onPress={() => setContent(otherUserContent)}>
        <Text>Click me!</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </>
  );
}
```

The important part is `key={someUniqueKey}`, without I get the different number of hooks error mentioned above.

Is this some hacky obscure solution, which will cause trouble down the road or is this legit?

Comment: As long as you can guarantee that number/order of hooks won't change while key remains the same you should be good

Comment: @OlegWock the number, the order and the hook change with the content, but then I should already ran into problems, no?

Comment: If you reset `key` when content changes, then no. From React standpoint, once `key` changes, it's different component for React. It doesn't matter if it's of same type (`<Markdown />`), as long as component calls same hooks in same order during it's lifetime (i.e. before it gets unmounted), React will be fine with it. And by changing keys you tell React to unmount component with older key and mount component with new key

Comment: There does not seem to be an error in the code snippet you posted. On which line does the error occur? Can you include the code where the error occurs?

Comment: By using `key={someUniqueKey}` where `someUniqueKey` changes with each "edit" or "instance" of the markdown, then no, I don't suspect you'll have any issues other than the additional incurred cost of tearing down and mounting React component instances.

Comment: @OlegWock @DrewReese: Okay, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks a lot!
@RossAllen: The Error occurs, when `key={someUniqyeKey}` is removed.